# Not able to get text from androidwebview using Appium

Tags: java, ui-automation, appium

java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

Appium 1.3.4.1

Android SDK 
ro.build.version.sdk=21..

Device used :- Nexus 7, 5.0.2

Hi,

I am using following code to get textual data from android.webkit.webview,
   but i m failing. Please help me .

Code used :-
   List  L1=(By.id("com.zimbra.client.zimbox:id/conversation_WebView"));
    List  L2=(By.className("android.webkit.WebView"));

L1.get(index).gettext() is not returning me text.

Answer (score 0):

To interact with a webview, a switch context would be required as below:

driver.context("WEBVIEW_webviewname");
WEBVIEW_webviewname - name as it appears in Appium log

Thanks,
Sujata